# Jasmine/Karma testing -- Spying on JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

In our test suite, we have spies on JSON.parse on one service spec whose return values seem to be spilling over into other component tests that use JSON.parse. Why would this be happening, and is there a fix for this?